# Call function pushing UIViewController inside closure as though it were outside

Tags: ios, swift, closures, pushviewcontroller

I have a closure (`handleMentionTap`) inside two other closure (`entireDescView.customize` (2nd closure) and `description` (1st closure)). Now I would like to call the function `pushProfileController(of: String)` which is located in the same class (in order to push another view controller (`newController`). The functions need to be called inside the closure since calling them outside it causes memory leaks for a reason I currently don't know (I am using a library called [ActiveLabel](https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift), didn't write it myself). However, the newController is not pushed (even though I use `DispatchQueue.main.async` as suggested in some answers on stackoverflow concerning similar problems). Nevertheless `newController` appears to be created and its data set (I am printing the data using `var passedData: String? { didSet { print(passedData) } }` ). How can I push the controller as though it were outside the closure (e.g. with `self.pushProfileController(of: username)`? I would really appreciate your help!

### swift (everyhting in the same class):

```
var pushingViewController = false

//...

func pushProfileController(of: String) {
    if self.pushingViewController == false {
        self.pushingViewController = true
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let newController = NewController()
            newController.passedData = of //passedData is a string
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newController, animated: true)
        }

        self.pushingViewController = false
    }
}

let description: ActiveLabel = {

    let entireDescView = ActiveLabel()

    //set properties of controls container view

    //recognize (@hotel_x) and be able to push controller of 'hotel_x'
    entireDescView.customize({ (entireDescView) in
        entireDescView.enabledTypes = [.mention]
        entireDescView.mentionColor = UIColor(red: 25/255, green: 153/255, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        entireDescView.handleMentionTap { username in
            self.pushProfileController(of: username) //also tried ThisClass().pushProfileController(of: username) which didn't push the controller either
        }
    })

    return entireDescView

}()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked `navigationController?` exists?

Try adding the following before attempting to push the viewController:

```
func pushProfileController(of: String) {
    if self.pushingViewController == false {
        self.pushingViewController = true
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let navController = self.navigationController else { return print("navigationController was nil") }
            let newController = NewController()
            newController.passedData = of //passedData is a string
            navController.pushViewController(newController, animated: true)
        }

        self.pushingViewController = false
    }
}
```